# Using Parameters in power bi query similar SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

In SSRS, we can use this query:

```
select name from Products where id = ?
```

and instead of ?, we create parameters to insert arbitrary value.
But in Power BI what is the solution? I don't want to change my query.
Thanks

Comment: You will definitely need to change your query. You aren't running over a relational source anymore, you're running over tabular now. You can't expect to just drop your SQL in and have it working. Here is one of many approaches to implementing parameters in Power BI / DAX: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/

Comment: Another solution is using a slicer. But your question is too general to understand what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Using slicer we need to change the query again.

Comment: You cannot expect to migrate SSRS to Power BI and have it work exactly the same. SSRS still has a _lot_ of functionality that Power BI _doesn't_ have and don't let anyone tell you otherwise!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid OK, so what is your suggestion?

Comment: *Using slicer we need to change the query again*   Why do you need to change the query?  If you are trying to display your SSRS reports as is within Power BI, [why don't you just embed them as SSRS reports?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards?view=sql-server-2017)  If you can't do that, I would still challenge whether you need to migrate your reports over;  remember that SSRS is a reporting tool and Power BI is a self-service Dashboarding/BI tool.  They are different tools that require different designs.

Comment: Your particular example, `select name from Products where id = ?` doesn't make a lot of sense. Is that query for a cascading prompt? (rather than anything populating a list or chart in a SSRS report). We need more context to pose a suggestion

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid For example this query: `select ? as 'Vendor_ID',
         count(distinct T.user_id) as 'Users'
from
(select user_id,address
from UsersAddresses UA
where 111.111*degrees((acos(cos(radians((select latitude from Vendors where id = ?))) * cos( radians( UA.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(UA.longitude) - radians((select longitude from Vendors where id = ?))) + sin(radians((select latitude from Vendors where id = ?))) * sin( radians(UA.latitude)) )))<= 3) as T inner join Orders O on O.customer_id = T.user_id`

Comment: That will have to be completely re architected for Power BI. I guess that is returning number of people that lived within a certain distance from vendors in a particular area? If you really need to convert it. You'd need to first create a DAX measure, then you'd need to substitute your parameter values into that DAX measure using the parameter table pattern that I posted on my first comment. This is one of the things SSRS does way better then Power BI

Comment: OR you can try and follow the 3rd google entry that I found: http://radacad.com/dynamic-distances-in-power-bi. This gives you an idea of the level of Power BI experience required to do this.